# Seeing number of e-mails in a folder in Mail

Tags: email

I'm on Mac OS 12.5.1. For flagged messages, Mail shows me the number of E-Mails with a certain flag, next to the folder that contains that flag like this:

[image]

Note that these e-mails do not have to be unread for this number to appear. It simply shows the number of blue flagged e-mails and the number of yellow flagged e-mails. In all other folders though, a counter only appears when e-mails are unread. I would like to display the number of e-mails in a folder in the same way as it appears here. I cannot find any settings that would allow me to do this.

What would  be a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please state the actual version of macOS, not 'current'. That ensures this question is still relevant in 2, 3, 4 years time. A question is for life, not just for Christmas.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @AndyGriffiths - I changed it.